# How in QEMU send mouse_move, mouse_button, sendkey via some api

Tags: api, qemu, kvm

Is it possible to send mouse_move, mouse_button, sendkey events via some kind of api from third party applications?

Comment: It may be possible via `libvirt`, but don't quote me on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `telnet`  option in the command line:

```
qemu-system-x86_64   -enable-kvm -m 1024   -monitor telnet:localhost:9312,server,nowait -drive file=my.img,cache=none
```

Then you can connect to that server using any socket API and send events to it:

```
echo 'sendkey i' | telnet localhost 9312
```